# Knex - Get users who have X or Y devices, but do not have a Z device

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I want to get users who have X or Y devices, but exclude all the ones who have a Z device. This is more or less how the table looks like

| user_id | device_type | resource_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | X | Device |
| 123 | Y | Device |
| 321 | Y | Device |
| 321 | Z | Device |
| 231 | Y | Device |
| 333 | Q | Other |

So the desired return would be users with ID 123 and 231, excluding 321 and 333 returned once each no matter how many devices they have.

I can manage to return the ones who have X or Y devices, but can't manage to exclude those with Z. This is how my call looks like for XY (original has a couple more columns):

```
knex
.select('user_id')
.groupBy('user_id')
.where('resource_type', 'Device')
.andWhere(function() {
this.where('device_type', 'X').orWhere('device_type', 'Y')
})
```

I tried to mix this with other where clauses like whereNot and others but couldn't make it work, users with device Z still showed up as if the clause was ignored. Could somebody please point me to the right direction? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I am not a Knex user but I think you are looking for [whereIn](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#wherein), so something like; `.whereIn('device_type', ['X', 'Y'])` instead of the `.andWhere(function()  ...`.

Comment: I've tried this and it still shows user_id 321, which has a Z device. Tried also the opposite with .whereNotIn, but still doesn't work as I wish.

Comment: For now I just filtered users with Z devices from all the returned users that have X and Y devices with javascript filter command. Kind of janky but works, will look to do it in one query in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```js
// First you create a subquery that will select the users with devices different from X and Y
const subquery = knex
  .select('user_id')
  .groupBy('user_id')
  .where('resource_type', 'Device')
  // Search users without X or Y device_type
  .whereNotIn('device_type', ['X', 'Y']);

// And then you search the users with device_type in X and Y, but not in the subquery
knex
  .select('user_id')
  .groupBy('user_id')
  .where('resource_type', 'Device')
  // Search users with X or Y device_type
  .whereIn('device_type', ['X', 'Y'])
  // Remove users that have at least a device different of X AND Y (those in the subquery)
  .whereNotIn('user_id', subquery);
```